# how to select rows with max value based on one column and group by second column using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

My data looks like:

```
1   161   a
1   48    b
1   30    c
2   199   d 
2   1306  d
2   1290  d
2   81    d
2   51    e
2   82    e
2   93    e
3   64    e
3   99    f
3   123   f
```

For every value in column three, I want to select row having maximum value in column 2 and group by column 1.
So the desired output is

```
1   161   a
1   48    b
1   30    c
2   1306  d
2   93    e
3   64    e
3   123   f
```

Grouping by column one I mean I want results for all the distinct values in column 1. What I tried using is

```
awk '$2>max[$3]{max[$3]=$2; row[$3]=$0} END{for (i in row) print row[i]}' file
```

I get the following result

```
1   161   a
1   48    b
1   30    c
2   1306  d
2   93    e
3   123   f
```

But I am missing the following row in the result

```
3   64  e
```

This is because this one liner is selecting just the maximum value in column 2 for the distinct values in column 3, How do I group this by column 1 to get the desired result for each value in column 1?

Comment: try sort -r -n -k2 < file| awk '\!x[$1,$3]++' | sort -k1

Comment: @soFan: I like the idea, but couple of fixes from your command `sort -r -n -k2 < file| awk '!x[$1 FS $3]++'  | sort -k1`, with this, the expected o/p is reached. I didn't want to put it up as answer as it was your original idea.

Comment: @inian , please feel free to do.

Comment: It works either ways, thank you, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to [`sofan's`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309601/sofan) idea over in the comments, with some extra manipulations the below logic will do the trick as the OP wants.

```
sort -r -n -k2 < file| awk '!x[$1 FS $3]++' | sort -k1
```

- Idea is to sort the file in ascending order first (`sort -n -k2`) and reverse it (`-r`) on column 2 (which now will be descending order)
- `awk '!x[$1 FS $3]++` does the grouping of that content unique by column 1 and 3 and `sort -k1` sorts/groups it by column 1 contents

Answer (score 5):

I think you can just use a composite key of `$1$3`:

```
awk '$2 > max[$1$3] { max[$1$3]=$2;
                      row[$1$3]=$0 }
                END { for (i in row) print row[i] }' file
```

Comment: Exactly as needed in OP! Having a most basic question though, I see people using variables like `max[$1$3]` as in your answer. How is this evaluated for the first time? Is it like all such variables will be `0` to start with?

Comment: @Inian I'm by no means schooled in AWK, but as to my best guess `max["not existing"]` would be evaluated to an empty string which in numeric comparison would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest command to find the maximum and minimum value in the second column is something like this, respectively

sort -nrk2 data.txt | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'
sort -nk2  data.txt | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `awk`. I had to use `tr -s " "` to suppress multiple whitespace separators between the fields/columns. The important line below is the second one.

```
cat $file | tr -s " " \
| sort -k2nr,2 | sort -k1,1 -k3,3 -u | sort -k3,3 -k1,1 -k2nr,2 \
| tr " " "\t"
```

Actually, the `-k2nr,2` at the very end is not even necessary. You could just retain the initial sort order with `--stable` instead. All roads lead to Rome.